# SQL: Count occurrence of a string in an array

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

| id | fav_meals |
| --- | --- |
| s1 | ["Chicken Nuggets", "Fish Sticks", "Beef Tacos", "Chicken Tacos", "Fish Tacos"] |
| s2 | ["Chicken Patty", "Beef Patty", "Nachos"] |

I have a table like the one above. I want to add a third column that, called taco_count which counts the amount of times the word 'taco' has appeared in the array. So, for the first row it'd count 3 times, the second row would count 0, and so on.

| id | fav_meals | taco_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | ["Chicken Nuggets", "Fish Sticks", "Beef Tacos", "Chicken Tacos", "Fish Tacos"] | 3 |
| s2 | ["Chicken Patty", "Beef Patty", "Nachos"] | 0 |

Comment: Amazon Redshift doesn't support arrays, so I'm a little confused on what you are asking.  Are the columns just strings?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select id, fav_meals
        , count(*) filter (where meal ilike '%Tacos%') taco_count 
        , count(*) filter (where meal ilike '%patty%') patty_count  
from (select * , unnest(fav_meals) meal from meals) t
group by id, fav_meals
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I do it if I were if I wanted to add mulitple columns. So one for taco_count and then one for patty_count?